# Get product by SKU

Tags: magento-1.8, product, sku

I want to get a product by sku, when i do from the admin area in manage products, i got a result but i noticed that magento stores the sku with two zeros added at the begging of the number.
The problem is when i try to the same programmatically using :

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
```

I got no result. How is the two things different ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grid filters in the admin panel use partial matching, they show a list of results that **contain** the text you entered.

`loadByAttribute()` uses exact matching to return one product with exactly the SKU that you entered. So you have to include the leading zeroes, which is by the way nothing that Magento adds automatically. It has to come from an extension or customization.

Comment: In fact, the products were imported using Magmi, but i don't know why it would add the zeros ...